# How to search through a LinkedList for an object with a certain variable in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this issue where I can populate a LinkedList with objects which I can manipulate later in this shop system I am designing. The problem is that when I populate the list with more than one Object and then search for that object in the List; my program will tell me that the object I am looking for doesn't exist even though I can list the contents of the list and it will show.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sales extends addVideoGame implements java.io.Serializable{

private static LinkedList<VideoGames> sellGame = new LinkedList<>();
private static String searchTerm;
private static int searchQ;

public static void sellItem(){
    sellGame = games;
    int listLength = sellGame.size();
    searchTerm = IBIO.inputString("What item would you like to sell: ");
    for(VideoGames v : sellGame){
    if(v.getTitle().contains(searchTerm)){
        IBIO.output("Item found: " + searchTerm);
        searchQ = v.getQuantity();
        IBIO.output("Available Quantity: " + searchQ);
        int sellQ = IBIO.inputInt("How much of this item would you like to sell: ");
        if(sellQ > searchQ){
            IBIO.output("The amount you have specified is greater than the \ncurrent stock.");
            sellItem();
        } else {
            searchQ = searchQ - sellQ;
            v.setQuantity(searchQ);
            double sellP;
            sellP = sellQ * v.getPrice();
            IBIO.output("£"+sellP);
            String confirm = IBIO.input("This is the price you are selling these items for. Type 'Yes' to complete the order or 'No' to reject it. ");
            if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                IBIO.output("Order complete!");
                try{
                    int receiptCount = 0;
                    PrintWriter receipt = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore\\receipt"+ receiptCount +".txt");
                    receipt.println("Item sold: " + v.getTitle());
                    receipt.println("Quantity sold: " + sellQ);
                    receipt.close();
                    receiptCount = receiptCount + 1;
                    IBIO.output("Receipt saved to: C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore");
                } catch(IOException io){
                    io.printStackTrace();
                }
                IBIO.output("Thank you for buying from Gamers Avenue UK!");
            } else if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("No") && TheStore.privilege){
                AccessMenus.adminMenu();
            } else {
                AccessMenus.userMenu();
            }
            if(TheStore.privilege){
                AccessMenus.adminMenu();
            } else {
                AccessMenus.userMenu();
            }
        }
    } else {
        IBIO.output("The item you are looking for does not exist.");
        sellItem();
    }
    }
}
}
```

Here are the classes used to navigate the program if anyone needs them:

```
public class TheStore {

static String password; //Variable created to hold and check the value of password against the correct value.
public static boolean privilege = false; //Variable created to distinguish the difference between a normal user and a user with administrator privileges.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IBIO.output("Welcome to Gamers Avenue UK!");
    IBIO.output("Please make sure that you enter the correct password for your given privileges.");
    password = IBIO.inputString("Enter password: ");
    if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){ //Checks the entered value against the correct value.
        privilege = true; //Sets global boolean value to true, so that admin access is granted.
        IBIO.output(" ");
        AccessMenus.adminMenu();//If password is correct, loads admin menu.
    } else if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("user")){
        privilege = false; //Keeps admin access off, so that unauthorised changes cannot be made.
        IBIO.output(" ");
        AccessMenus.userMenu();//If correct, loads user menu.
    } else {
        IBIO.output("The password is incorrect. Exiting program."); 
        System.exit(1); //If an incorrect password is entered, the program will close.
    } //close else
}//close main
}//close class TheStore
```

Access Menus:

```
public class AccessMenus{

    public static int choice;//Variable which will hold the value, which corresponds to an action depending on what value is entered.

    public AccessMenus(){ //Null argument constructor, to set values to 0.
        AccessMenus.choice = 0;
    }

    public AccessMenus(int c){ //Single argument constructor.
        AccessMenus.choice = c;
    }

    public static void userMenu(){
        IBIO.output("1: Sell a product.");
        IBIO.output("2: Register a customer in the Loyalty programme.");
        IBIO.output("3: Stock check.");
        IBIO.output("4: Log out.");
        IBIO.output(" ");
        IBIO.output("Please make your choice: ");
        choice = IBIO.inputInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            Sales.sellItem();
        } else if(choice == 2){
            CustomerRandom.customerMenu();
        } else if(choice == 3){
            StockCheck.checkStock();
        } else if(choice == 4){
            IBIO.output("Logging out.");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            IBIO.output("Invalid choice. Returning to menu.");
            userMenu(); //If the value entered does not correspond to any action, the program will treat it as invalid and return to the menu.
        }//close else
    }//close userMenu

    public static void adminMenu(){
        IBIO.output("1: Sell a product.");
        IBIO.output("2: Go the Videogame management menu.");
        IBIO.output("3: Stock check.");
        IBIO.output("4: Register a customer in the Loyalty programme.");
        IBIO.output("5: Log out.");
        IBIO.output(" ");
        IBIO.output("Please make your choice: ");
        choice = IBIO.inputInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            Sales.sellItem();
        } else if(choice == 2){
            addVideoGame.vgMenu();
        }else if(choice == 3){
            StockCheck.checkStock();
        } else if(choice == 4){
            CustomerRandom.customerMenu();
        } else if(choice == 5){
            IBIO.output("Logging out.");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            IBIO.output("Invalid input. Returning to menu.");
            adminMenu();
        } //end else
    }//close AdminMenu
}//close AccessMenus
```

This class is necessary as it allows you to populate the list:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class addVideoGame extends VideoGames implements java.io.Serializable{

public static VideoGames game = new VideoGames();
public static VideoGames eGame = new VideoGames();
public static LinkedList <VideoGames> games = new LinkedList<>();
public static LinkedList <VideoGames> loadList = new LinkedList<>();
private static int vgChoice = 0;
public static int vgCount = 0;
public static int vgAmount = 0;

public static void vgMenu(){
    IBIO.output("WARNING: USING OPTION 4 TO LOAD IN A LOCAL FILE WILL ERASE EVERYTHING CONTAINED IN THE CURRENT LIST. \nSave everything in the current list using option 3 before loading in data.");
    IBIO.output("1: Add a new videogame to the list.");
    IBIO.output("2: View the contents of the list.");
    IBIO.output("3: Save the contents of the list to the local area.");
    IBIO.output("4: Load in data from a local file.");
    IBIO.output("5: Return to the main menu.");
    vgChoice = IBIO.inputInt("Make your choice: ");

    if(vgChoice == 1){
        vgAmount = IBIO.inputInt("How many games would you like to add to the database?: ");
        for(int x = 0; x < vgAmount; x = x + 1){
        VideoGames vg = new VideoGames(); 
        vg.setTitle(IBIO.inputString("Enter the title of the game: "));
        vg.setPublisher(IBIO.inputString("Enter the publisher of the game: "));
        vg.setDeveloper(IBIO.inputString("Enter the developer of the game: "));
        vg.setAgeRating(IBIO.inputInt("Enter the age rating of the game: "));
        vg.setGenre(IBIO.inputString("Enter the genre of the game: "));
        vg.setQuantity(IBIO.inputInt("Enter the available quantity of the game: "));
        vg.setPrice(IBIO.inputDouble("Enter the recommended retail price: "));
        game = vg;
        games.add(vg);
        IBIO.output(" ");
        }
        vgMenu();
    } else if(vgChoice == 2){
        IBIO.output("Current amount of games in the list: " + games.size());
            Iterator itr = games.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Object g = itr.next();
                IBIO.output(g + " ");
            }
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(games.toArray()));
        vgMenu();
    } else if(vgChoice == 3){
        try{
            ListIterator output = games.listIterator();
            while(output.hasNext()){
            Object o = output.next();
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore\\games.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(game);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            IBIO.output("Data saved to C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore\\games.ser");
            }
        } catch(IOException io){
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
        vgMenu();
    } else if(vgChoice == 4){
        eGame = null;
        try{
            ListIterator input = games.listIterator();
            while(input.hasNext()){
            Object i = input.next();
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore\\games.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in =  new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            eGame = (VideoGames) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
            games.clear();
            games.add(eGame);
            IBIO.output("Item added to list from local file.");
            }
        } catch (IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
            IBIO.output("VideoGames class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();;
            return;
        }
        vgMenu();
    } else if(vgChoice == 5){
        IBIO.output("Returning to main menu: ");
        AccessMenus.adminMenu();
    } 
}     
}
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Too much code. Post just enough to reliably demonstrate your problem. Refer to [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm still relatively new to this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the bug is cause by the `else`-block inside the loop inside `sellItem()`.
Try this (although still I think you should remove the call to `sellItem()` inside the final if):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sales extends addVideoGame implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static LinkedList<VideoGames> sellGame = new LinkedList<>();
    private static String searchTerm;
    private static int searchQ;

    public static void sellItem(){
        sellGame = games;
        int listLength = sellGame.size();
        searchTerm = IBIO.inputString("What item would you like to sell: ");
        boolean foundItem = false;
        for(VideoGames v : sellGame){
            if(v.getTitle().contains(searchTerm)){
                foundItem = true;
                IBIO.output("Item found: " + searchTerm);
                searchQ = v.getQuantity();
                IBIO.output("Available Quantity: " + searchQ);
                int sellQ = IBIO.inputInt("How much of this item would you like to sell: ");
                if(sellQ > searchQ){
                    IBIO.output("The amount you have specified is greater than the \ncurrent stock.");
                    sellItem();
                } else {
                    searchQ = searchQ - sellQ;
                    v.setQuantity(searchQ);
                    double sellP;
                    sellP = sellQ * v.getPrice();
                    IBIO.output("£"+sellP);
                    String confirm = IBIO.input("This is the price you are selling these items for. Type 'Yes' to complete the order or 'No' to reject it. ");
                    if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                        IBIO.output("Order complete!");
                        try{
                            int receiptCount = 0;
                            PrintWriter receipt = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore\\receipt"+ receiptCount +".txt");
                            receipt.println("Item sold: " + v.getTitle());
                            receipt.println("Quantity sold: " + sellQ);
                            receipt.close();
                            receiptCount = receiptCount + 1;
                            IBIO.output("Receipt saved to: C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheStore");
                        } catch(IOException io){
                            io.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        IBIO.output("Thank you for buying from Gamers Avenue UK!");
                    } else if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("No") && TheStore.privilege){
                        AccessMenus.adminMenu();
                    } else {
                        AccessMenus.userMenu();
                    }
                    if(TheStore.privilege){
                        AccessMenus.adminMenu();
                    } else {
                        AccessMenus.userMenu();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!foundItem) {
            IBIO.output("The item you are looking for does not exist.");
            sellItem();
        }
    }
}
```

And while this may work I would generally advise to transform `searchTerm` into an argument to the function and `searchQ` to the return value of the function. Doing so increases isolation between concurrent processes and clarifies which parameters are needed for the correct execution of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was the issue causing it not to thoroughly search through the list. It works fine now! :D